# Is there any plugin that encrypt/decrypt a base64 URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-storage

I have created a chrome app , i want to store the encrypted base64 URL of a video file using chrome.Storage.local API so that no one can use that URL to play that video in Offline mode only authenticated user can play .

I have search about chrome.Storage API, there i find the statement "Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted." Thats why i want to encrypt that base64 url.

Thanx.

Comment: What do you mean by safe?  Safe from what?  And, how are you doing the encryption?  Where are you storing the encryption keys?  And, where is the video file stored?  Evaluating security-related questions need to understand the entire context from the goals to everything that is being done because security is only as good as the weakest link.  Right now, you're basically asking: "I have this kind of lock on my front door.  Is my house safe?".  The answer is that it depends not only on the lock on the front door, but on a whole bunch of other things which you have not disclosed.

Comment: Encrypted keys are stored using Chrome.Storage.local API .
All videos url are stored in API .
Actually , after downloading video user can play them in offline mode and in offline mode blobUrl expires after some time, thats y i need to store/save base64 URL.

Comment: I asked you a whole bunch of questions.  You only answered one.  Security questions have to be answered in a broader context.  For example, now we also need to know where the video is stored and how you are securing that too?

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, not an encryption!

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is not encryption, it's *encoding*. The difference being that encryption uses a secret key to control access to the data, while encoding requires no key. Without a key involved in the process, anyone who knows the algorithm can decode the data.

***Base64, as well as any other encoding algorithms, should not be used to protect the confidentiality of data.***

Daniel Miessler has an [article](https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/) which goes into slightly more detail about the differences and use cases of encryption vs encoding, and also covers hashing.

Answer (score 1):

`Base64` can be easily decrypted back to normal because it's two-way algorithm (while `md5` is one-way algorithm.). Never save any sensitive information in user accessible location.

It would be better to request a **new** **URL** each time, and add some *expire* time for that **generated** **URL**.

Comment: Actually i have created a base64 url of a video using Reader API of chrome and then stored that base64 URL using Chrome.Storage.local API.
Is there any another way to ecncrypt/decrypt base64 URL

Comment: @NitikaMds Yes, base64 is simply every symbol converted to symbols that has base 64 instead of 8. Just google `base64 decode`